# Change title iframe (that has no id) within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to figure out how to add a title to a iframe that has no 'id' using javascript.

The code is like this:

```
<div class="review-right">
<div>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to get this:

```
<div class="review-right">
<div>
<iframe title="Sample"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".review-right iframe").attr('title', 'Sample');
});
</script>
```

I'm a noob at jquery so I don't know if this is even right.

Comment: what did you try? can you post a snippet?

Comment: I've added the code i've tried, but didn't work

Comment: Try ditching the dot in your class name: Change this `<div class=".review-right">` to this `<div class="review-right">`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.` from `.review-right` class in the HTML and in the Script just use basic DOM

```js
document.querySelector(".review-right div iframe").title = 'Sample Vanilla'
```

```html
<div class="review-right">
  <div>
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.review-right iframe').prop('title', 'Sample Jquery');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-right">
  <div>
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My mistake, the '.' wasn't supposed to be there of course.

Anyhow, that unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer with a method for jquery try that one @Max